# AWS SNS - Failing to add Entries to PublishBatch Via Postman

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, postman, publish-subscribe, amazon-sns

I am trying to use the PublishBatch action with REST Api Via Postman.

when trying to add the "publishBatchRequestEntries", getting the error:

'Top level element may not be treated as a list'

Probably not writing the Query Param Key correctly.

What is the correct way to do this?

[My REST Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJWhY.png)